# Setting environmental variables in Ubuntu 16 Service

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, tomcat8

I'm currently attempting to upgrade a web application server from Tomcat 7 to Tomcat 8 however I am running into an issue with setting the environmental variables in Tomcat 8.

In Tomcat 7 we copy a configure-env-vars.sh script into /etc/profile.d/

```
#!/bin/sh

export ENV_VAR=$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server-config.properties
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xms512m -Xmx2048m -server -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
export SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION=file:${ENV_VAR}
```

Then in /etc/init.d/tomcat7 start script we input a line `. /etc/profile` that would set the environmental variables that the application would need at launch.

However, this method is not working with Tomcat 8 and no environmental variables are being set to indicate the location of the properties file that the application needs in order to run.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working yesterday by dropping the `#!/bin/sh` and relocating the file to `/etc/default/configure-env-vars` and performing the following check in `/etc/init.d/tomcat8`:

```
case "$1" in
  start)

    # Setting environmental variables needed for the Spring Application
    TOMCAT_HOME=/home/ubuntu/tomcat
    [ -f /etc/default/configure-env-vars ] && . /etc/default/configure-env-vars

    if [ -z "$SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION" ] ;  then
            echo "SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION is not set, please set it in /etc/default/configure-env-vars" >&2
            exit 1
    fi
```